# Does buffing grant you Turret assists?

Tags: league-of-legends

Yes we all know that Attacking a turret will grant you extra gold when it dies.

Now my question is a bit weird: What happens if you don't deal any direct damage to a turret but you buff an allied Champion or minion that finishes off a turret? Does that count as a turret assist? I know that if you shield a turret as Janna and it finishes off a champion, you will get the kill even if you haven't dealt any direct damage to the killed champion. Is it the same for other buffs on other targets?

For a more vivid description: 3 Scenarios with Soraka (I don't like her she just has some nice buffs)

1. I'm At my base and I need 50 gold. Now waiting isn't really effective but luckily Ashe is about to destroy the enemy bottom turret so I use my ult.
2. Me and Ashe are mid and we're about to kill the turret. The enemy Syndra approaches and Ashe drops really low. I accidentally heal the Cannon minion that attacks the turret instead of Ashe but at least the turret goes down. (I didn't throw a banana at the turret)
3. Ashe Ragequitted because I heal minions and use my ult randomly. I'm alone at the bottom turret but I don't want to go too far in So I just heal a random caster minion that is attacking the turret and then I leave. The turret dies within 10 seconds.

Now in which of the 3 above cases would I actually gain bonus gold?

Comment: I'd also like to know how it works with aoe buffs : for exemple I have Jarvan with Locket, do I get gold from standing near a hero attacking the tower? If not, do I get it if I place the flag so he gets the attack speed boost, with me still not attacking tower?

Comment: This might be the hardest question on here. When I have spare time next week, I'll test this. My feeling tells me you ave to give it a direct hit, so buffs wouldn't help.

Comment: "i didnt throw a banana" :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are referring to the change introduced in [patch 3.14](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-314-notes#patch-map-objectives) stating that turrets grant additional gold that is "split among the players who participate in destroying the turret".

It turns out, this wording is very misleading. The reality is that any champion standing within the turrets range when it is destroyed will receive a portion of the bonus gold, regardless if that champion has done any damage to the turret. The converse is also true, if a champion has done damage to a turret recently but is outside of its range when it is destroyed, they will not receive any of the bonus gold.

This phrasing makes it more clear:

> Outer turrets now grant 100 global gold to each player and an additional 150 gold is split among the players who are within range of the the turret when it is destroyed.

Youtube user Kuralesache explains this well and demonstrates the behavior in this video:

This means that none of the scenarios that you describe would grant you a portion of the bonus gold (you would only receive the global gold).

Answer (score 0):

(Not sure if I understood correctly your question...)

Assists doesn't work with turrets.

When you destroy the turret and watch the right side of your HUD, it will display who did the last hit, but not who helped. However, money reward after destroying the turret is distributed to everyone in your team, and therefore, it is irrelevant to know who helped.

Now, if you do have special companion summoned by your champion, such as Yorick's ghost (when dead), Mordekaiser's ghost, Tibbers, Malzahar's creature, Heimerdinger's turrets, etc. it will count as you destroyed the turret.

Comment: according to [lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Turret) (and personal experience) you will gain bonus gold for participating in killing the outer and middle turret: `When an Outer turrets is destroyed, each member of the destroyer's team gains 100 global gold, and 150 gold are split among the players who participate in destroying the turret. No experience is gained.` I just don't know how the distribution actually works and what actually counts as "Participating"...

Comment: Wow, then THERE IS extra gold if you hit a turret before your fellow does the last hit... Hmm, I should consider deleting the answer, but I'll leave it here until I have time to check it out.

Comment: @Fabián This is actually a recent change (last couple of months I think). Before this it was just global gold. They nerfed the global gold but added in the last-hit bonus.

Comment: @Jutschge I will admit it has been quite some time since the last time I played LoL, so I may be completely off base here. However I seem to recall "participation" in a turret kill (for that extra 150 gold) is based off distance. Everyone on your team near the turret splits that 150, whether or not they actually help damage it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the "assist gold" for turrets is based purely on distance from the tower when it goes down. Source: Jatt and Deman during LCS saying something along the lines of "Stop moving away from the dying towers! You're missing out on the **local** gold!" As for what counts to give you the turret assist, I'm not sure.